# what is my error?

Tags: c, file-io, fopen, std

my compiler says: save is undeclared... i declared it by "FILE *save"

```
FILE *save
save = fopen ("filename.txt", "w");

while ( current != NULL )
{
    fprintf (save, " %s %s %d", current -> name, current -> tel, current -> age);
    current = current -> next;
}
```

Comment: You missed a `;` at the end of the first line.

Comment: Why not give your answer as an answer?

Comment: You're not supposed to edit the question so that existing answers become invalid.

Comment: @unwind anyways there stayed the semicolon in your edit...

Comment: sorry... my account cant post any questions anymore

Answer (score 2):

```
FILE *save
save = fopen ("filename.txt", "w");
```

Missing semicolon here:

```
FILE *save;
```

Comment: whoa.... sorry... i didnt notice that.... thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semi-colon at

```
FILE *save
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing a semicolon at the end of the first line?

```
FILE *save;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing `;` :

```
FILE *save ;
           ^
```